# Mix hard-float ABI with code that runs without VFP/NEON

Tags: gcc, arm, neon

#### Scenario

My target platform is ARM cortex-A7 with VFP/neon enabled, where my system software running on the target platform does not always turn VPF/neon on but turn on VPF/neon only on demand (by calling some system API).
My tool chain is a bare-metal GCC-4.7.4 cross-compiler on pc-cygwin host (arm-none-eabi).

We have a C source file `a.c`, the code may run when system software turns VPF/neon off.  This `a.c` code is **pure integer** with intensive `long long` (64-bit integer) operations.  If applying the GCC option `-mfloat-abi=hard` or `-mfloat-abi=softfp` to compile `a.c`, some instructions to use VFP/neon registers will be generated (such as, `vldr d7,[..]`, `vstr d7,[sp,..]`, etc).  If running this generated code when VFP/neon is off, an undefined fault happens on target platform.  If applying the GCC option `-mfloat-abi=soft` to compile `a.c`, no VFP/neon register will be used and solve the undefined fault problem.

On the other hand, there is another C source file `b.c`, which contains floating points/vectors (VFP/neon) operations and runs only if when system software turns on VFP/neon.  I'd like to compile `b.c` with the GCC option `-mfloat-abi=hard` instead of `-mfloat-abi=softfp` for performance reason.

If `b.c` is compiled with `-mfloat-abi=hard` and `a.c` is compiled with `-mfloat-abi=soft` option, they cannot be linked together and the linker will complain: "...Uses VFP register arguments, XXX does not".

#### Question

Is there any way (with tool chain GCC options, installation configurations, versions) to compile the said pure integer `a.c` compatible with hard-float ABI (passing floating point arguments via VFP/neon registers) but without generating any VFP/neon instruction or register for pure integer operations?

#### Notes

- As a workaround, `a.c` with option `-mfloat-abi=soft` and `b.c` with option `-mfloat-abi=softfp` can be linked, but poorer performance is not desirable.
- The [GCC 4.9 release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html) said “.. Use of Advanced SIMD (Neon) for 64-bit scalar computations has been disabled by default. This was found to generate better code in only a small number of cases. It can be turned back on with the `-mneon-for-64bits` option”. This seems to be related to my problem, but I am using GCC 4.7.4.

Answer (score 0):

You should stick to the `softfp` option regardlessly.

In fact, there is no difference between `hard` and `softfp` at all when no parameter of type `float` is passed.

Even if it's the case, `softfp` causes a very small overhead at the beginning outside of possible loop. (moving the contents of ARM registers to VFP registers, and eventually some loads from the stack when there are more than four parameters)

Since the vfp doesn't support `int64`, the instructions starting with a `v` must be NEON ones. You should try `-fno-tree-vectorize` to disable the stupid auto vetorization that gets enabled automatically with the `-o3` option.

PS: If you are so performance aware, why don't you write optimized NEON codes? Properly hand written NEON codes make jaw dropping differences unlike the annoying auto vectorized ones that are utterly useless.